# Replaced a custom Comparator with Comparator.comparing() - why does this work?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have a `List<Meeting>` and Meeting is as follows:

```
public class Meeting {
    private Calendar date;
    public Calendar getDate() {
      return this.date
    }
}
```

In originally had a Custom lambda comparator in the `.sorted()` portion of a stream (`myMeetingList` is a `List<Meeting>`) :

```
return myMeetingList.parallelStream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getContacts().contains(contact))
                    .sorted((m1,m2) -> m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I stumbled across something completely by accident. I think it works, but I have no idea why. Instead of creating the custom Comparator I replaced it with what looks like a static method reference:

```
return myMeetingList.parallelStream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getContacts().contains(contact))
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Meeting::getDate))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I believe it works, but I honestly don't know why. The JavaDoc for one of the implementations of `Comparator.comparing()` shows

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

but have searched a few blogs and read through the doc a few times, and  I'm having a hard time deciphering that. Reading my actual code makes sense, but I couldn't have derived that on my own without checking the example in the JavaDoc. Anyone have any ideas on how to better explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `Comparator.comparing` is just:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);

return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
```

The first line is just a check that the parameter is not null.

The second line returns a `Comparator` which just calls the `keyExtractor` function to get the values to compare and uses their `compareTo` method to do the compare. The generics in the declaration of `comparing` ensures that `keyExtractor` must implement `Comparable`.

In your case the `Meeting::getDate` method reference will produce a `keyExtractor` function which just calls the `getDate` method, so

```
keyExtractor.apply(c1)
```

will execute

```
c1.getDate()
```

So the end result is essentially the same as your original code.

Comment: Thank you, so the Comparator<T> in this case is a Comparator<Calendar> ?

Comment: Yes `T` will be inferred as `Calendar`